# groupby by multiple variables using Altair

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, visualization, altair

I have a dataset that contains timestamps roughly every 15 minutes for several years, weather stations (two stations), solar zenith angle (sza), and categorical column that contains values such as TN, TP, FN, FP.

| time | station | sza | Hit/Miss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-09-01 00:15:00 | LFPG | 122.520350 | FN |
| 2016-09-01 00:30:00 | LFPO | 119.658256 | TP |

and so on.

I would like to make a plot where I can see how many of each category of Hit/Miss belong to which sza bin every month during the study period.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
alt.Chart(df_paris).mark_rect().encode(
    x=alt.X('month(time):O', title=None),
    y=alt.Y('year(time):O', title=None),
    color=alt.Color('sza', bin=True),
    row=alt.Row('station', title=None),
    column=alt.Column('Hit/Miss:N', title=None),
).resolve_axis(x='independent')
```

And the result looks like this:

[image: result1]

Does each pixel represent a monthly mean sza of each categorical value? Because what I want is the exact number of every category that belongs to a certain sza bin every month and every year. Essentially, I want to find out if there's any correlation between the frequency of Hit/Miss values and sza depending on the time of year.

I have also tried this:

```
alt.Chart(df_paris).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('year(time):O', title=None),
    y=alt.Y('count(Hit/Miss):Q'),
    color=alt.Color('Hit/Miss', legend=alt.Legend(title=None), 
                    scale=alt.Scale(range=['#5c8fff', '#ffcc5c', '#96ceb4'],)),
    column=alt.Column('month(time)', title='Monthly Aggregates 2016-2022'),
    row='station'
    
).resolve_axis(x='independent')
```

which gives me: [image: result2]

but with that I can't see the sza distribution.

I read about aggregate and groupby in altair docs, but I'm still very much lost.

I'm pretty new at statistical analysis and python altogether, and would welcome any learning opportunities if you'll have any feedback for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Does each pixel represent a monthly mean sza of each categorical value?

To represent an aggregate value like a mean, you need to use [an aggregation function](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encoding.html#binning-and-aggregation). In this case you should write `alt.Color('mean(sza)')` (and optionally add the color binning if that is important for your application, I am not sure I see the purpose).

If you don't add an aggregation function, there will be one marker per row in the dataframe. Since you are using `mark_rect` the markers will be stacked on top of each other and you can only see the last (topmost) one. Here is an example of how mark are plotted on top of each other (using `mark_square` to allow for different sizes to more clearly illustrate what is going on in the example).

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [0, 0, 0],
    'y': [0, 0, 0],
    'c': [1, 2, 3],
    's': [3, 2, 1],
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_square(opacity=1).encode(
    x='x:O',
    y='y:O',
    color='c:O',
    size='s:O'
)
```

[image]

Reversing the order of the dataframe will cause the largest square to be on top which covers the others:

```
alt.Chart(df.sort_values('s')).mark_square(opacity=1).encode(
    x='x:O',
    y='y:O',
    color='c:O',
    size='s:O'
)
```

[image]